# how to use $regex search in referenced field in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i am struggling with a task, which it is I used two schemas

```
User Schema
{
  "first_name": String,
  "last_name":String,
  "address": String
}

Employee schema
{
  user:{
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
  },
  gross_pay: String,
  net_pay: String
  tax: String,

}
```

Well, how can I search first_name using $regex in Employee Schema in this user referenced field? I tried in so many ways, can't get it. how can i resolve it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Approach:**

Using [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation

```
Employee.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "let": { "user": "$user" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$user"] }}},
      { "$project": { "firstName": 1 }}
    ],
    "as": "user"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$user" },
  { "$match": { "user.firstName": { "$regex": your_string, "$options": "i" }}}
])
```

But it is not the better approach as the [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage is being applied to all the `Employee` documents and then [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to the users `firstName` makes the query bit slow.

**Second Approach:**

First find the users having `firstName` equal to the match string using `$regex` and then find the `_id` in the `Employee` collection.

```
const userIds = await (Users.find({ "firstName": { "$regex": your_string, "$options": "i" } })).map(user => user._id)

const employees = await Employee.find({ "user": { "$in": userIds }})
```

**Third Approach:**

Keep the single key `firstName` of the `user` schema in the `employee` schema

Employee schema

```
  user: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  gross_pay: String,
  net_pay: String
  tax: String
  firstName: String
```

and then use query directly

```
const userIds = await Employee.find({
  "firstName": { "$regex": your_string, "$options": "i" }
})
```